# @inherited also make @Overrided methods values inherited the annotation?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface, annotations

i'm working with a lot of interface inherited and annotations lately and I have a doubt about @Inherited annotation. I know that by default java annotations are not inherited for subclasses and methods. Using the @Inherited annotation we can make the annotation be inherited by the subclasses.

But it also work with the annotated values in the method constructors?

For example:

```
@Inherited
@StringDef({ID_REAR, ID_FRONT})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface CustomId {
}

public interface Setting {
   void update(@CustomId String myCustomId);
}   

public class CustomSetting implements Setting{

   @Override public void update(String myCustomId) {

   }
}
```

In this case, will the method `update` from `CustomSetting` implement the annotation`@CustomId` for his contructor `(String myCustomId)` ?

Comment: No. Read the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) of the `@Inherited` annotation, which say: "Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class."

Comment: Understand,  there's no way to do inherite for the method values then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jesper answer above, the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) is very clear about it: The @Inherit annotation doesn't work with anything other than a class:

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.